# PostgreSQL - running DELETE command concurrently on different rows

Tags: postgresql

We have a very large PostgreSQL database and to do some cleanup we need to delete lots of rows from one table, but every row there has a relation (I don't know if that's a proper english name for it) to other rows in other tables. What I mean is that running simple `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = 14217` also removes many different rows from other tables. And this process takes a long time, about 10-15 seconds for one row and it would take 20 whole days (24/7) to finish it. I'm wondering if I can run these DELETE operations concurrently (multiple instances of our software running delete operations, each on different set of rows). I have read that DELETE uses ROW EXCLUSIVE lock so theoretically it only locks one row, so it should be possible to do without locking our software for normal users. We have very fast server with SSD drives, plenty of ram & cores so hardware is not a problem. Will it speed up the whole process, or will we be still limited by something?

Comment: Perhaps some of the foreign keys that reference your table [have no indexes](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/index-your-foreign-key/)?

Comment: Perhaps you can post the plan for the query

Comment: I checked for those indexes using "How to check for missing indexes?" from that page and there were some missing, but not with tables that were used in that DELETE query. I then checked with developer of that software and after some testing we came to a conclusion that it is slow because one trigger also deletes some rows from other table which has almost 3 milion rows. And we also tested multiple delete operation running at the same time and it looked like they were fine, no slowdowns, waits, etc, so I will just leave it like this and delete them using multiple instances of that software.